# Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir

Tags: node.js, apostrophe

I keep getting this error with Apostrophe CMS even with fresh installation over windows 10. Any help will be appreciated. thanks

This is the error :

> \node-apostrophe\projectname\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:123
>       process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
>
> Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir

Answer (score -1):

Just ran into the same problem using *nodemon* to watch for file changes.

Looks like when output is written to public directory it triggers nodemon again, causing permission errors on those folders.

Ignoring public in nodemonConfig fixed it for me.

```
  "nodemonConfig": {
     "verbose": true,
     "ignore": [
        "lib/modules/*/public/js/*.js",
        "locales/*.json",
        "public/modules/**/*.less",
        "public/modules/**/*.js",
        "public/uploads",
        "public/apos-minified/*.js",
        "public/css/master-*.less",
        "data",
        "public" //<-- add this
    ],
    "ext": "json, js, html, less"
}
```